# Jetpack compose Canvas content disappears after I make it scrollable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

```
Canvas(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize().horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
)
```

For some reason whenever I add horizontalScroll to the modifier of my Canvas, all the content in my canvas disappears. I don't know why. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Using a horizontalScroll, you should define the size of the Canvas, otherwise it take 0.dp as default.

Comment: it didn't work :/. Also the size was already defined with fillMaxSize

Comment: No,with fillMaxSize and horizontalScroll it can't work. In this case you have to provide also a fixed size, otherwise the canvas takes 0.dp as default.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens to me, but in my case with a LazyColum, when I compose it generates the items that enter the screen and when I start to scroll, the bottom ones are not loaded, and if I go back up some are lost.

Answer (score -2):

You'd need to use a fixed size for the canvas. E.g.

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        .padding(16.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
        .width(1400.dp)
        .height(4000.dp)
) { ... }
```

Comment: There has got to be a way to solve this without using a static pixel value. What about something that utilizes fillMaxWidth()?